# GAE blobstore url error: GET not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am having trouble with the google app engine blob store. I am running in the development environment (ie local on my machine.)

Heres what i am doing...

once the form pops up i call into a servlet to generate the URL like this

```
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("test/joi");
```

once i have that i save it in my java scrip and then once the user submits the form i am doing this

```
$.ajax({ url: self.url,
        type: "POST",
//crossDomain: true,
dataType: "jsonp",
//dataType: "multipart/form-data",
success:    
function(response, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
  alert("saved.");
    }
 });
     }
```

however, when i do that i get the following exception

GET  405 (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL) jquery.js:4

i am really struggling with this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell from your browser's Network tab (Chrome or Firebug will show you this) whether the error is happening on the initial post, or on the subsequent redirect to your test/joi URL?

Comment: possibly me not specifying the call back?

Comment: @greg i am looking in the networking tab and i have this as the URL its trying to feed the (Request URL:http://jesse-reims-macbook-air.local:8888/_ah/upload/ag1wc3ljaHNlbGVjdG9ychsLEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YPww?callback=jQuery172018804047163575888_1341680368131&_=1341680388712) however my gae instance is running at localhost.... i was under the assumption that the url that it showed would be something the gae needed to write the blob down...

Comment: it appears to be on the initial post

Comment: You need to show us the code for your blobstore upload handler, too.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from any other issues, the blobstore expects file uploads in multipart form format; you're attempting to post to it using jquery. If you want to do the post in javascript, you will need to format the body of the POST request appropriately.